# Close Reasons: Too Localized?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8725/letter-of-intent-help) @OregonGhost mentioned, that the question is "too localized / too specific" meaning it will most likely not carry any significance to anyone else visiting this site.

When voting to close I could close as OT for translation request, but what would happen when the question is not closable for any of the given reasons? Should we thus introduce a close reason:

> "too localized - this question is very likely not to help any future visitors" ?

Answer (score 2):

The predefined close reason "Too localized" was dropped system wide. See here for reasons and discussion:

- [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

Basically, the idea behind this was that if a question was "too localized" it will always be off topic too.

Because there always will be bordeline cases, when the "general interest" may not be so obvious for a given, otherwise fairly interesting question. We as a community are free to keep such questions, i.e. not close them, or to edit them to emphasize a general interest that may still be inherent. Interestingly there are not too few questions which felt like very localized but have quite a lot of views. So it may not always be us to decide what the pulic likes to see or not.

To still tell a user that the question lacks general interest, or is "too localized" we can always give this as a custom close reason in an editable text entry when closing a question as off topic:

[image]